HCLA second architecture
im facing a problem with calculating the gate delay of HCLA second architecture, it should have a constant gate delay (8 gate delays), but when i try to calculate the gate delay, i get 7 gate delays. so in the picture c8=G0+P0c0 where: G0=g7+p7g6+p7p6g5+...+p7p6p5p4p3p2p1g0, and P0=p7p6p5p3p2p1p0, the second picture shows what are g7...g0 and p0...p7, and i believe that the circuit in the second picture is implemented in each block of the first picture


now this is how the gate delay is
calculated:
it takes two more gate delays to produce the carry signals c8, c16, and c24 than the time needed to generate the Gj and Pj functions. Therefore, since Gj and Pj require three gate delays, c8, c16, and c24 are available after five gate delays. The time needed to add two 32-bit numbers involves these five gate delays plus two more to produce the internal carries in blocks 1,2, and 3, plus one more gate delay(XOR) to generate each sum bit. This gives a total of eight gate delays.
now my question is that WHILE calculating c8 arent we already using the output of the and gates in the second level of the second picture so when we calculate the gate delay of c8 or c16 ... theres no need to add the gate delay of the second level and gate from the second picture to calculate the gate delay of the internal carries in blocks 1,2, and 3. so please explain to me how this is done

so theres the first archi and the second archi, the first archi c16 depends on c8 and so on(so theres ripple carry between blocks) in the second archi c8,c16 and the rest depend on c0 so its basically 2 different ways of implementing.
